# How to do inline paste from system buffer in Vim?

Tags: vim

When pasting from the system buffer in a line like

```
foo( someVal , <cursor is here>, someVal3);
```

If I use "*p I get

```
foo( someVal, , someVal3);
<pasted text>
```

If I use "*P I get

```
<pasted text>
foo( someVal, , someVal3);
```

but I want

```
foo( someVal, <pasted text>, someVal3 );
```

How can I get the result I want?

**edit**

If there is a newline in the buffer as @amardeep suspects, is there a way I can tell vim to ignore it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can type `<C-r>*` in insert mode and then use `<BS>` to remove trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

Use capital P instead of lower case p in that command.

Comment: then the pasted text is above the line.  Updating question with example.

Comment: It worked fine when I tried it.  The text in your buffer might have newlines in it.

Comment: newlines would be fine, at least it would result syntactically correct code :)

Answer (score 0):

`"*p` or `"+p` works for me. Are you sure that's what you're actually typing?